# Combine XML files

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, linq-to-xml

As part of our build process in Visual Studio we need to combine multiple (200+) xml files into a single file. Our challenge is that the individual files are maintained at varying depths within the xml structure.

Here is a simplified example of what we are trying to do:

File 1: The UI configuration for Object 1's UI

```
<configuration>
    <group name="UI">
      <group name = "Object 1">
        <setting name="label" value="This is Object 1">
        <setting name="mode" value="edit" />
        <setting name="etc" value="..." />
      </group>
    </group>
</configuration>
```

File 2: The UI configuration for Object 2's UI

```
<configuration>
    <group name="UI">
      <group name = "Object 2">
        <setting name="label" value="This is Object 2">
        <setting name="mode" value="edit" />
        <setting name="etc" value="..." />
      </group >
    </group>
</configuration>
```

File 3: Schedlue config

```
<configuration>
    <group name="Scheduler">
      <setting name="numTaskRunnerThreads" value="1" />
      <setting name="sleepTimeSeconds" value="60" />
      <list name="jobs">
        <group name="Job 1">
        </group>
      </list>
    </group>
</configuration>
```

When the build is run, these 3 files would need to be merged to produce the following struture.

```
<configuration>
    <group name="UI">
      <group name = "Object 1">
        <setting name="label" value="This is Object 1">
        <setting name="mode" value="edit" />
        <setting name="etc" value="..." />
      </group>
      <group name = "Object 2">
        <setting name="label" value="This is Object 2">
        <setting name="mode" value="edit" />
        <setting name="etc" value="..." />
      </group >
    </group>
    <group name="Scheduler">
      <setting name="numTaskRunnerThreads" value="1" />
      <setting name="sleepTimeSeconds" value="60" />
      <list name="jobs">
        <group name="Job 1">
        </group>
      </list>
    </group>
</configuration>
```

Files 1 and 2 have been mergered within the "UI" node and file 3 has been merged within the "configuration" node. This merge is based, logically, on finding the deepest common node between the file structures.
Note: in the real world, these deppest common nodes can be 5 or 6 layers deep in the structure and new nodes can be added at any depth.

Any ideas on how we would perform this type of merge would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you want to handle collisions?

Comment: Good question. Collisions should cause the build to fail.

Comment: What programming language.  Visual Studio could mean vb.net, c#, or even Visual Studio SQL.

Comment: Any of the above, but my preferrence would be C#